# Mock request without rest template bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, integration-testing

I trying to mock rest template request in integration test. The problem is that rest template is not a bean and creating using new keyword.

```
restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
resttemplate.postforentity(...) // need to mock

    private synchronized RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    if (restTemplate == null) {
      // set interceptors
    }
    return restTemplate;
}
```

how can i mock this request?

Comment: If you are testing integration why you wanto to mock request?

Comment: If you want to mock a server that is called from your system under test, you may want to take a look at [the citrus framework](https://citrusframework.org/).

Comment: why not declaring `restTemplate` as bean ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [`MockRestServiceServer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html).

Something like this:

```
MockRestServiceServer.MockRestServiceServerBuilder builder = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate);
mockServer = builder.build();
```

and somewhere in the code, something like this:

```
mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.manyTimes(), requestTo(new StringContains("<some string>")))
                    .andRespond(withSuccess("<JSON body>"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

There are lots of matchers and ways to stub requests, read the docs, please.

Comment: i don't have rest template instance under test

Comment: I think you may need to rethink the architecture of your project